# For how long is it okay for sump pump to stay broken?

Tags: foundation, water-damage, sump-pump, soil

There is a sump pump in the subfloor area of a basement. The sump pump has stayed broken for several months. After inspecting the sump pump recently we found that there is no water. Which is somewhat surprising. I can also subjectively tell that the bottom of the sump pump well has raised. Can we expect the worse?

A few questions:

- how long a sump can stay broken before the soils actually expand?
- If the soils did expand, should we dig up the well more?
- Is there generically a way to reverse the expansion?

I hope for the best but trying to prepare for the worse. Thanks for any comments/ answers!

Edit 1: our neighborhood is known for expansive soils.

Edit 2: the plumber service is scheduled for tomorrow. I am just trying to think if we now should dig that well up so it is again as deep as it was, as I believe the bottom of the well went up.

Comment: I would be more concerned with water flooding out of the sump pit and into your basement than with soils expanding. In homes with relatively shallow sump pits, I've seen them go from bone dry to requiring a pump to run non-stop in the course of a couple hours. I'd strongly suggest you not try to risk it; get the sump pump repaired or replaced now.

Comment: Thanks, added a couple of edits to the post to clarify

Comment: You can leave it be and wait until it is needed, just be sure to have it operational before your basement gets flooded.

Comment: Somewhere between 30 seconds and forever, depending on the need for a sump pump at all.

Answer (score 3):

If the pumps been dry, how do you know it's not functioning? If you haven't done it, pour a few or more gallons into the sump to see if it kicks on.
Sump pumps are installed for a good reason. Usually it's to keep your basement dry and free of water damage. Water tables and groundwater vary according to atmospheric conditions and season. The fact that it's dry now doesn't necessarily mean that it'll be dry next month or next week. You need to get that pump running if it isn't operable.
Concerning the expanding ground. Many areas have expansive soils such as bentonite but expansive soils generally expand due to moisture, not lack of it. Also, sump pumps are fixed in place. If the soil does expand significantly (a) it could damage the pump and/or (b) the sump pit becomes so small that it won't contain incoming water.
The best thing you can do right now is make sure that pump is operational.

Comment: I know it has been off since it broke earlier we put a new one in, but the pipe work didn’t work out, and we left it off

Comment: "Many areas have expansive soils such as bentonite but expansive soils generally expand due to moisture, not lack of it" - my point was that the floor of the sump pump has raised enough that the standing water level in the soil became lower than the bottom of the well, hence it's "dry" now .. but that's just the hypothesis